# SQL Conversion to Date And/Or Time From Character String Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RPost_Receipts]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [branch] [int] NULL,
    [policyref] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [receipt_email_received] [datetime] NULL,
    [receipt_email_to_openattach] [int] NULL,
    [receipt_email_to_openattach_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [sender_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sender_address] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [subject] [varchar](160) NULL,
    [message_id] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [time_received] [datetime] NULL,
    [delivery_to] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [delivery_status] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [delivery_report] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [delivery_time_utc] [datetime] NULL,
    [delivery_time_local] [datetime] NULL,
    [time_opened] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the following `UPDATE` query I am attempting to run on the same table

```
UPDATE [FreshSystems].[dbo].[RPost_Receipts]
SET [sender_name] = 'RPost eSignOff Service' ,
    [sender_address] = 'contracts@usw.rpost.net' ,
    [subject] = 'Re: REF: 02-OGKX02PC01 Your Insurance Policy (2 of 2)' ,
    [message_id] = '49B918875098C1EFCB5A33FDB2D446FF5C294ACE' ,
    [time_received] = '9/15/2015 10:36:29 AM' ,
    [delivery_to] = 'AutoSaintCS@Fresh.co.uk' ,
    [delivery_status] = 'Delivered to Mailserver' ,
    [delivery_report] = '250 OK id=1ZbnbS-0003fY-4y engine03-30179-2.icritical.com (192.162.216.4)' ,
    [delivery_time_utc] = '9/15/2015 10:36:47 AM' ,
    [delivery_time_local] = '9/15/2015 10:36:47 AM' ,
    [time_opened] = 'NULL'
WHERE [branch] = 02
  AND [policyref] = 'OGKX02PC01'
  AND [delivery_to] IS NULL
```

Why am I receiving a conversion error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The inserts are going into 'DATETIME' columns and the datetime's that are being inserted are all correctly formatted, can anyone shed any light on this for me please?

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to occur ONLY within my VB.NET Application. When running the statement in SQL Server Management Studio it is fine, when it executed within my VB.NET it fails as a conversation from character to Datetime.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [`SET DATEFORMAT mdy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) and/or use [**ISO-8601**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) format for datetime literals.

Comment: you can comment suspicious columns one by one. After finding the error column then re-think again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is you were trying to put the word `NULL` into the `time_opened` field. (which is a datetime field)

Change it from `[time_opened] = 'NULL'` to `[time_opened] = NULL`

```
UPDATE  [FreshSystems].[dbo].[RPost_Receipts]
SET     [sender_name] = 'RPost eSignOff Service' ,
    [sender_address] = 'contracts@usw.rpost.net' ,
    [subject] = 'Re: REF: 02-OGKX02PC01 Your Insurance Policy (2 of 2)' ,
    [message_id] = '49B918875098C1EFCB5A33FDB2D446FF5C294ACE' ,
    [time_received] = '9/15/2015 10:36:29 AM' ,
    [delivery_to] = 'AutoSaintCS@Fresh.co.uk' ,
    [delivery_status] = 'Delivered to Mailserver' ,
    [delivery_report] = '250 OK id=1ZbnbS-0003fY-4y engine03-30179-2.icritical.com (192.162.216.4)' ,
    [delivery_time_utc] = '9/15/2015 10:36:47 AM' ,
    [delivery_time_local] = '9/15/2015 10:36:47 AM' ,
    [time_opened] = NULL
    WHERE   [branch] = 02
    AND [policyref] = 'OGKX02PC01'
    AND [delivery_to] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Datetime format is yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and not 9/15/2015 10:36:29 AM
Convert it before updating table.